# Recover Activities discarded by Trello when moving cards from one board to another?

Tags: trello

I improved the organization of my Trello boards by consolidating similar cards into a new board. I'm very sad that Trello did not warn me that one side effect of moving the cards was the discarding all the Activities. I've been keeping vital information in Activities and now have lost weeks of accumulated information.

Is there any way to recover?

Comment: I doubt there is anyway to, but maybe the Trello dev's will comment and be able to help you out!

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is a Trello bug which is fixed

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug and your comments are not lost. There is a card for the issue here: https://trello.com/c/3i8QmHLW

Comment: What about those cards whom have had activity since they were moved? Can I save the current activities, move the card back to the previous board, then, restore the current activities?